# Why does these instances not produce the Overlapping Instances error

Tags: haskell

Let's define a `collapse` function that collapses any possibly nested `Maybe (Maybe (... a)...)` to `Maybe a`:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE IncoherentInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoOverlappingInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module MaybeCollapsable where

class M a b where
  collapse :: Maybe a -> Maybe b

instance (a ~ b) => M a b where
  collapse = id

instance M a b => M (Maybe a) b where
  collapse Nothing = Nothing
  collapse (Just a) = collapse a
```

It works well

```
> collapse (Just (Just (Just 1)))
Just 1
```

Although, it is strange. Both instances seems to be matchable for that particular case (`a ~ Maybe x` and `b ~ Maybe x`) but compiler produce no `Overlapping Instances` error.

How it works with `-XNoOverlappingInstances`?

And, by the way, is it a safe and usable way to define such method for collapsing nested `Maybe`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem might be that `IncoherentInstances` is overriding the `NoOverlappingInstances` directive.  If you remove `IncoherentInstances` the code gives an overlapping instances error.  The GHC manual is not clear on this ( http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#instance-overlap ) but the two flags do clearly relate.

If you turn off `IncoherentInstances` and turn on `OverlappingInstances` your code works fine.  So drop the `IncoherentInstances` flag, and I think the behaviour will be as you initially expected: the overlapping instances flag makes the different between working and not working.